# Error with "onclick method" running under the IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

Im using the following code to display content into a new window as a popup and it's working on local host

```
 <a onclick="window.open('/UsuarioTI/SCyOC.aspx?Number=<%# Eval("num_solicitud") %>','targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=400,height=420');" ><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>SC/OC</a>
```

I tried to put my project into the IIS and it display this error (this doesnt appear while im running my project trought local host) :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its 
dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is 
temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that 
it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /UsuarioTI/SCyOC.aspx
```

How to fix this? The button has a dynamic data from an "asp repeater".

Comment: This may seem obvious, but did you confirm on the server that there is a folder called `UsuarioTI` in the root of the site and that it contains the page `SCyOC.aspx`?

Comment: @VDWWD the site contains the definition for "SCyOC.aspx". I had to had "the app name" before the tag to fix on server, but it's fine running as local.